# Converting Activity to a fragment gives onCreateOptionsMenu error

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I was converting my UserListing Activity to a fragment when i received this error in myOnCreateOptionsMenu.

[image]

This is my Fragment Activity.

```
public class UserListingActivity extends Fragment implements LogoutContract.View {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTabLayoutUserListing;
    private ViewPager mViewPagerUserListing;

    private LogoutPresenter mLogoutPresenter;

    public static void startActivity(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserListingActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static void startActivity(Context context, int flags) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserListingActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(flags);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        bindViews();
       init();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    //    @Override
//    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_listing);
//        bindViews();
//        init();
//    }

    private void bindViews() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mTabLayoutUserListing = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_user_listing);
        mViewPagerUserListing = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_pager_user_listing);
    }

    private void init() {
        // set the toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        // set the view pager adapter
        UserListingPagerAdapter userListingPagerAdapter = new UserListingPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mViewPagerUserListing.setAdapter(userListingPagerAdapter);

        // attach tab layout with view pager
        mTabLayoutUserListing.setupWithViewPager(mViewPagerUserListing);

        mLogoutPresenter = new LogoutPresenter(this);
    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_listing, menu);
//        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
//    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
                getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_listing, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_logout:
                logout();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void logout() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.logout)
                .setMessage(R.string.are_you_sure)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.logout, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mLogoutPresenter.logout();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LoginActivity.startIntent(this,
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutFailure(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

What has to be changed to solve this and what more has to be changed to covert it into a Fragment. I am beginner so detailed help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: simply `override` the method in fragment , you will see the difference , FYI , it should be `void`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the return type of the method, make it `void` and error will be gone as the `super-type` returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Method signature in fragment should be as below

**public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)**